# Float:left not working

Tags: html

Can some one please help me on this..
I am using float:left for id =row1 but why doesnt it get alinged.

There are two columns of data using div for each list, both list should be alinged to left, not below one another.

http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/1878/

```
<style>
#row1{
float:left;
}
</style>


<style>
.col1{

margin-left:50px;
width:150px;
border:1px solid;
border-color:red;
}
</style>

<style>
.col2{

margin-left:100px;
width:150px;
border:1px solid;
border-color:red;
}
</style>

<!--one coloum-->
<div class="col1" id="row1">Sr No:</div>
<div class="col1">Entry Date:</div>
<div class="col1">Name</div>
<div class="col1">Phone No:</div>
<div class="col1">Email ID:</div>
<div class="col1">MRF Code:</div>
<div class="col1">Location:</div>
<div class="col1">Total Exp:</div>
<div class="col1">Last Organisation:</div>
<div class="col1">Current CTC:</div>
<div class="col1">Notice Period:</div>
<div class="col1">Source:</div>

<!--second column both needs to be side by side-->
<div class="col1" id="row1">Sr No1:</div>
<div class="col2">Entry Date1:</div>
<div class="col2">Name1</div>
<div class="col2">Phone No1:</div>
<div class="col2">Email ID1:</div>
<div class="col2">MRF Code1:</div>
<div class="col2">Location1:</div>
<div class="col2">Total Exp1:</div>
<div class="col2">Last Organisation1:</div>
<div class="col2">Current CTC1:</div>
<div class="col2">Notice Period1:</div>
<div class="col2">Source1:</div>


</body>
```

Any help appreciated..

Comment: You probably heard that tables layout is bad and outdated, but this is exact case when you need to make table from your data.

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means the best way of doing what you're trying to achieve here - you're better off looking at tables rather than divs. But if you're really set on keeping this sort of structure, you need a wrapper div round each column, with the display set to inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/1880/

```
<!--one coloum-->
<div style="display:inline-block">
<div class="col1" id="row1">Sr No:</div>
<div class="col1">Entry Date:</div>
<div class="col1">Name</div>
<div class="col1">Phone No:</div>
<div class="col1">Email ID:</div>
<div class="col1">MRF Code:</div>
<div class="col1">Location:</div>
<div class="col1">Total Exp:</div>
<div class="col1">Last Organisation:</div>
<div class="col1">Current CTC:</div>
<div class="col1">Notice Period:</div>
<div class="col1">Source:</div>
</div>

<!--second column both needs to be side by side-->
<div style="display:inline-block">
<div class="col2" id="row1">Sr No1:</div>
<div class="col2">Entry Date1:</div>
<div class="col2">Name1</div>
<div class="col2">Phone No1:</div>
<div class="col2">Email ID1:</div>
<div class="col2">MRF Code1:</div>
<div class="col2">Location1:</div>
<div class="col2">Total Exp1:</div>
<div class="col2">Last Organisation1:</div>
<div class="col2">Current CTC1:</div>
<div class="col2">Notice Period1:</div>
<div class="col2">Source1:</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much...I forgot to mention this is my first ever attempt. I have just completed the course at Codeacademy and trying to build a User interface for data filling. The 1 field are going to be input.